# Codename One days left in current week or month

Tags: date, calendar, codenameone

I am building a calendar application that needs to calculate the remaining days of (1) the current week and (2) the current month.

What I have tried was using the java.util.Calendar API, but it seems not to be fully supported.

```
int days = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

How would I do this in CN1?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would love to add support for [JSR310](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp/) in the future which would probably solve this in a more elegant way. This is something that can be done as a cn1lib without modifying Codename One but would require some work...

A bit of a hack to do this is:

```
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
if(month == cal.DECEMBER) {
   cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1);
   cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
} else {
   cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month + 1);
}
int day = 24 * 60 * 60000;
cal.setTime(new Date(cal.getTime().getTime() - day));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know CN1, but you can calculate the values using a subtraction between the max and the current value:

```
(1) cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)

(2) cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

For your notification: The first day of the week is sunday in the api of calendar. When your week should start with monday you have to reduce the offset by 1.

Comment: Koenig, apparently, CN1's calendar API does not support .getActualMaximin() method. Thanks anyway.